# How to export a transaction from Plutus for the wallet

Tags: plutus, transaction, nami-wallet, pab

I have a contract that returns an unbalanced transaction:

```
buyTokensTx :: forall w s. TokenPool -> BuyParams -> Contract w s Text (Either MkTxError UnbalancedTx)
```

From what I understand, I need to export this unbalanced transaction from the PAB and import it into the Nami wallet in a CBOR serialised format. In `Plutus.Contract.Wallet`, I found a function that does just this:

```
export :: C.ProtocolParameters -> C.NetworkId -> UnbalancedTx -> Either CardanoAPI.ToCardanoError ExportTx
```

This `ExportTx` seems to wrap the CBOR I need, as one can conclude from its toJSON:

```
-- IMPORTANT: The JSON produced here needs to match the schema expected by
-- https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/balanceTransaction
instance ToJSON ExportTx where
    toJSON ExportTx{partialTx, lookups, redeemers} =
        object
            [ "transaction" .= JSON.encodeByteString (C.serialiseToCBOR partialTx)
            , "inputs"      .= lookups
            , "redeemers"   .= redeemers
            ]
```

(see: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/plutus-contract/src/Plutus/Contract/Wallet.hs)

My problem is that `export` takes as its two first arguments `ProtocolParameters` and `NetworkId`. Where do I get these ? And also, where is the best place to call this `export`-function ?